# Heroku CLI Error: create is not a heroku command

Tags: macos, heroku, homebrew

I have created heroku applications from the terminal before, but for some reason, this is not working for me:

```
$ heroku create my-app
```

I get the following result

```
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
 ▸    create is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant update
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

I updated my `brew` to have the latest version of heroku. When I run `heroku -v` I get:

```
heroku-cli/6.15.11 (darwin-x64) node-v9.3.0
```

I'm also pretty sure it is installed correctly. When I run `which heroku` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/heroku
```

One weird clue seems to be that `heroku help` gives me the following:

```
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Usage: heroku COMMAND

Help topics, type heroku help TOPIC for more details:

 auth
 plugins  add/remove CLI plugins
```

Which seems like it clearly does not include `create` as one of the commands, so do I need to add `create` somehow? I know that `create` is shorthand for `apps:create` so I tried both and got the same result.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I recently updated to Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: I had got the similar problem with heroku-cli/6.15.11-5cba33c (linux-x64) node-v9.3.0 and I fixed it by updating to heroku-cli/6.15.13-3dce47c (linux-x64) node-v9.3.0

It might be not needed. Firstly, I would suggest removing _~/.local/share/heroku/client_ as you can find within [heroku/cli/issues/673](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/673#issuecomment-355760412)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same problem.  The only solution I found was to uninstall from homebrew, and then manually install the heroku-cli package from here https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli.pkg
I only experienced this after upgrading to High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please, make sure your path variable are setup correctly
2. Please, make sure that you are logged in to your account.

You can login using following command from command line:

```
$ heroku login
Email: <your email>
Password: <your password>
```

3. navigate to the root folder in your system where you want to host application locally and try with your command.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a bigger issue than originally expected. Today (after trying the suggestion in the comments), I realized I was also having issues with node (I was unable to `npm init` anywhere). I ended up completely reinstalling macOS.

When that didn't work, I [erased and reinstalled macOS completely](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065). After reinstalling node and heroku through brew, it did work.

I know erasing and reinstalling macOS is a pretty drastic option, but it didn't seem like anything else was working. I'm hoping there's a better answer out there, but I just wanted to include this in case someone else stumbled upon this question.